# How to align items with ionic css utilities?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm doing a small UI with ionic, and I'm looking about the css utilities(https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities ).

I've this UI:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-grid >
    <ion-row  class="ion-align-items-center">
      <ion-col size="4" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-avatar ><ion-img [src]="(loggedUser$ | async).avatarUrl"></ion-img></ion-avatar>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="8" >        
        <ion-label  >
          <h2>{{ (loggedUser$ | async).userId }}</h2>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

but currently, the `ion-avatar` is on the left of his `ion-col`.

Is there a way with those Ionic css utilities to center the ion-avatar in the middle of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra div as shown.

From what I have seen the reason is how ionic framework creates the shadow dom. If you don't explicitly add the div to which to add the CSS util, ionic applies it in the wrong spot.

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-grid >
   <ion-row  class="ion-align-items-center">
     <ion-col size="4">
      <div class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-avatar ><ion-img [src]="(loggedUser$ | async).avatarUrl"></ion-img></ion-avatar>
      </div>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col size="8" >        
    <ion-label>
      <h2>{{ (loggedUser$ | async).userId }}</h2>
    </ion-label>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```